# Kubernetes Persistent volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have this MYSQL database pod running within a google cloud cluster, also using a persistent volume(GCEpersistentdisk) to backup my data. 
Is there a way to also have a AWS persistent volume(AWSElasticBlockStore) backing up the same Pod, in case something goes wrong with google cloud platform and can't reach any of my data, so when I create another Kubernetes Pod within AWS, I'll be able to get my latest data(before GCP crushes) from that AWSElasticBlockStore.
If not what's the best way to simultaneously backing up a kubernetes database pod at two different cloud provider. So when one crushes, you'll be still able to deploy at the other.

Comment: You want to fail between clouds? Are you using federation? I think your best bet is to replicate mysql to handle HA, then if you loose a pod, you've got a working database still until that issue is resolved.

Comment: I want to use one cloud as a back-up if for some reason the other where I'm currently running goes down or crushes or block me from accessing my data. I just started to learn about federation but I haven't seen any database example associated with it, if you know any tutorial please direct me to it.